# SQLite Join multiple tables ordering by less COUNT

Tags: sqlite, join, group-by, count

I have this database structure:

[image]

I need to display the `users` which can perform a `Task` of a determinate type on one specific day, showing first the results which has less `Tasks` (or don't have any `Task`) assigned to that day.

For example:

- `User` A has 1 `Task` of type 1 assigned that day.
- `User` B has 3 `Task` of type 1 assigned that day.
- `User` C has no `Task` of type 1 assigned that day.

I want to display them in this order: User C > User A > User B

Here is my query:

```
SELECT  *, COUNT(*)
FROM USER U
INNER JOIN USER_TASK_TYPE UT ON (U._id=UT.user_id)
LEFT JOIN TASK T ON (U._id = T.user_id)
where UT.TASK_TYPE_ID = ?
where T.CREATION_DATE = ?
GROUP BY T.user_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC;
```

Something is still wrong because if one `User` has 1 task assigned, and another `User` has none, still the  first `User` is being shown first.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the schema provided does not reflect the query being used :-

- There is no **creation_date** column in the **task** table.
- The **id** column for the **user** table should be **_id**.

Second the query you have provided will result in a syntax error due to **WHERE** being coded twice.

Your description of what data exists is unclear e.g. you say :-

> User A has 1 Task of type 1 assigned that day

What row(s) exists in what table?

As a guess the following has been used

- Noting that :-

  - Multiple users exist for which no tasks exist
  - and a user exists for which no task on the day exists

:-

```
-- DROP and Recreate/Create tables
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS task;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS task_type;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_task_type;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  name TEXT, user_id INTEGER, user_name TEXT, password TEXT, user_type TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS task(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, creation_date TEXT, description TEXT, duration int, status TEXT, user_id INTEGER, task_type_id INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS task_type(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_task_type (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, user_id INTEGER, task_type_id INTEGER);

-- Add some users
INSERT INTO user (name,password,user_type) VALUES
    ('USER1','x','x'),('USER2','x','x'),('USER3','x','x'),('USER4','x','x'),('USER5','x','x'); 

-- Add some task types
INSERT INTO task_type (name) VALUES
    ('Sweep'),('Wash'),('Polish'),('Scrub');

-- Add some tasks for users
INSERT INTO task (creation_date, description, duration, status, user_id, task_type_id) VALUES
    ('2018-01-01','USER1 TASK01',10,'to be done', 1,1),
    ('2018-01-01','USER2 TASK01',10,'to be done', 2,1),
    ('2018-01-01','USER2 TASK01',10,'to be done', 2,1),
    ('2018-01-01','USER2 TASK01',10,'to be done', 2,1),
    ('2018-02-02', 'USER3 NOT ON THE DAY',10,'to be done another day',3,1) --<<<< for testing user on another day
    -- ('2018-01-01','???????',10,'????????',3,1); commented out used for testing
    ;

-- unclear what this is used for but match tasks SUPERFLUOUS?
INSERT INTO user_task_type (user_id, task_type_id) VALUES
    (1,1),(2,1),(2,1),(2,1),(3,1),
    (3,1) -- added a spurious row;
    ;

SELECT  *, COUNT(*)
FROM USER U
    JOIN USER_TASK_TYPE UT ON (U._id=UT.user_id)
    JOIN TASK T ON (U._id = T.user_id)
WHERE UT.TASK_TYPE_ID = 1
-- WHERE T.CREATION_DATE = '2018-01-01' <<<<<<<<<< Invalid used the following line
AND T.CREATION_DATE = '2018-01-01' -- <<<<<<<<<< assumed AND
GROUP BY T.user_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC;
```

The result is what appears to be as expected (no spurious row for users who have no task or who have no tasks on the day). However, the count is not as expected but is the count squared. :-

[image]

I believe that the issue with the count is with/using the user_task_type table which appears to be redundant and problematic. So the following may well be along the lines of what you want :-

```
SELECT  *, COUNT(*)
FROM USER U
    -- INNER JOIN USER_TASK_TYPE UT ON (U._id=UT.user_id)
    JOIN TASK T ON (U._id = T.user_id)
    JOIN task_type tt ON tt.id = t.task_type_id
WHERE  tt.id = 1 AND T.CREATION_DATE = '2018-01-01'
GROUP BY T.user_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC;
```

This results in :-

[image]

- i.e. The user_task_type table hasn't been joined as it appears to serve no purpose and the count is as expected